# jQuery mask for different card types

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking

I have a credit card input, and its mask should dynamically change after input change events (e.g. its default mask is "9999 9999 9999 9999", but for "37" it should change to AMEX format "9999 999999 99999").

When I'm typing is fine, but when I copy/paste it doesn't format correctly.

```js
$('input').on('input', function (e) {
  var value = $(this).inputmask('unmaskedvalue');

    $('input').inputmask({
      mask: (value.substr(0,2) === '37' || value.substr(0,2) === '34') ? '9999 999999 99999' : '9999 9999 9999 9999'
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/inputmask/4.0.9/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input>

<p>
Try switching between the these two (paste first, then second then first again):
</p>
<ul>
  <li>5100000000404390</li>
  <li>370000000024291</li>
</ul>
```

Any idea where can be wrong?

Comment: Your code sample works correctly for me when I copy and paste the values, the format changes correctly: https://i.imgur.com/8q1sm4e.png & https://i.imgur.com/ODxhX4v.png. This is using both latest Chrome and Firefox for Win10

Comment: And in safari works fine. In which browser does format not work correctly?

Comment: Please try first version, after second, after first again. I'm using latest Chrome in Mac and I got this (5100 0000 0040 439_) when I copy 5100000000404390 second time.

Comment: I think it something to do with delay issue. Maybe the formatting runs quicker than the moment of the paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just jump in and read the documentation https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

This is what I can help so far

**update:** using [alternator](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#alternator-masks)

```js
$('#cc').inputmask({
  mask: '(3(4|7)99 9{6} 9{5}|3999 9{4} 9{4} 9{4}|9{4} 9{4} 9{4} 9{4})'
}).change(function(){
  let value = $(this).val().substr(0,2);
  $('#vv').inputmask({
    mask: (value==34||value==37)?'9{4}':'9{3}'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/inputmask/4.0.9/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input id="cc"/>
<input id="vv"/>
<p>
Try switching between the these two (paste first, then second then first again):
</p>
<ul>
  <li>5100000000404390</li>
  <li>370000000024291</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work either, and normal typing is also not good.

Comment: @levipadre you are right the normal typing is messed up, although the copy paste is working on safari

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right about the paste.

Comment: Thanks @Atmahadli, this seems really good so far! I will run some test, but we probably have a winner.

Comment: Can you maybe help me with CVV input as well? Basically if card start with 37 or 37, CVV should be 4 numbers, otherwise 3. I tried with unmaskedvalue, but it seems it doesn't work tohether with alternator.

Comment: @levipadre you can just use jquery to get the curent value and apply the mask to the other input, check my updated

Answer (score 0):

You are not compensating for change in length of mask. Just change your mask for AMEX to 9999 999999 99999[9]

```
$('input').on('input', function (e) {
 var value = $(this).inputmask('unmaskedvalue');

   $('input').inputmask({
     mask: (value.substr(0,2) === '37' || value.substr(0,2) === '34') ? '9999 999999 99999[9]' : '9999 9999 9999 9999'
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @aGosavi, it sound good, but when you paste 370000000024291 it shows 3700 0000 0024 291_